# Who is the one choosing the weapons

Tags: grammar, meaning

In the below sentence, I was wondering who was the one choosing the weapon. The shop attendant had come over and asked them what kind of weapons they were looking for. And the more experienced adventurer helping the others responded with the below:

> えーっと……。俺と相談しながら各自の武器を選ぶってことで。

I looked at this and first thought that it would mean something like "they(the people the more experienced adventurer is helping) will consult with him and choose their own weapons" but then I thought, if that was the case why would it not be 各自**が**武器を選ぶ instead of 各自の武器を選ぶ. Which then made me wonder whether there is difference in meaning in this wording, or whether I am overthinking things. I say this because I know that when using しながら the subject of the two verbs needs to be the same, so whoever the people doing the choosing also need to be the people discussing with him.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first thought is correct. 各自が武器を選ぶ is also natural. The subject of 俺と相談しながら各自の武器を選ぶ is "the people whom the more experienced adventurer is helping". It is (各自が)俺と相談しながら(各自が)各自の武器を選ぶってことで.